# Why does my code add an extra frame in front of my animation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I've been coding a Python program that will take a list from a different program, take specific values from that list, and add them to a 2D list. This subsequently creates an animation, with one frame per sub-list within the 2D list. However, when it's animated (using Celluloid), an extra frame is added in front of it that displays a graph of every sub-list at once, which disrupts the animation.

The code I'm using is this:

```
#Imports the relevant parts of the external modules
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from celluloid import Camera
from main import projectileInfo, tickRate

displacements = [] #A 2D list of all displacements

for i in projectileInfo:
    displacements.append([i[1], i[0]])

print(displacements)

fig = plt.figure()
camera = Camera(fig)

for j in displacements:
    x = [j[0]]
    y = [j[1]]
    
    plt.plot(x,y, color = '000000', marker = '.') #Plots the data as black points

    camera.snap()

ani = camera.animate(interval = 1000*tickRate, repeat = False)
plt.show()
```

The issue doesn't come up if I specify values for the animation within the code itself (e.g. `displacements = [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]]`, but it does if projectileInfo is specified within the program.

For reference, examples for projectileInfo and tickRate are provided:

```
projectileInfo = [[0, 0, 2.944881550342992, 0.5724269861296344, -1.0092420948384448, -0.03813290516155552, -12.052760210752101, -0.08473978924790115], [0.2944881550342992, 0.05724269861296344, 1.739605529267782, 0.5639530072048443, -0.35217721337929575, -0.03701225346578069, -10.592616029731769, -0.0822494521461793], [0.4684487079610774, 0.11363799933344787, 0.6803439262946049, 0.5557280619902264, -0.05386624698009846, -0.03594051938005718, -9.929702771066887, -0.0798678208445715], [0.5364831005905379, 0.1692108055324705, -0.3126263508120839, 0.5477412799057693, 0.011373937998969578, -0.0349148868178283, -9.784724582224511, 
-0.07758863737295177], [0.5052204655093295, 0.22398493352304744, -1.291098809034535, 0.5399824161684741, 0.19398969267459468, -0.03393274001211678, -9.378911794056458, -0.07540608891581507], [0.376110584605876, 0.27798317513989484, -2.2289899884401807, 0.5324418072768926, 0.5781971273919331, -0.03299164661811001, -8.525117494684594, -0.07331477026246667], [0.1532115857618579, 0.3312273558675841, -3.0815017379086402, 0.5251103302506459, 1.1050566133054158, -0.0320893424586703, -7.354318637099077, -0.07130964990815623], [-0.15493858802900617, 0.3837383888926487, -3.816933601618548, 0.5179793652598302, 1.6954652941177968, -0.031223717732420407, -6.042299346404897, -0.06938603940537869], [-0.536631948190861, 0.43553632541863174, -4.421163536259038, 0.5110407613192923, 2.2747457012945764, -0.030392804526055698, -4.75500955267872, -0.0675395656134571], [-0.9787483018167649, 0.486640401550561, -4.89666449152691, 0.5042868047579466, 2.7903609807178054, -0.029594765491590475, -3.6091978206270996, -0.06576614553686772], [-1.4684147509694558, 0.5370690820263556, -5.25758427358962, 0.4977101902042599, 
3.216860139839751, -0.02882788356578406, -2.6614219114672206, -0.06406196347952013], [-1.9941731783284178, 0.5868401010467816, -5.523726464736342, 0.49130399385630785, 3.5507821034099836, -0.028090552623374627, -1.9193731035333705, -0.062423450274165834], [-2.546545824802052, 0.6359705004324124, -5.715663775089679, 0.48506164882889125, 3.801833041871401, -0.027381268968280633, -1.3614821291746655, -0.06084726437395696], [-3.11811220231102, 0.6844766653153016, -5.851811988007145, 0.47897692239149553, 3.985110999814779, -0.026698623577869795, -0.9541977781893805, -0.05933027461748843]]
```

```
tickRate = 0.05
```

I haven't managed to reproduce the problem in any test program, not even within the same virtual environment as the original code.

Comment: to me your code is working fine, and I am importing projectileInfo and tickRate from a info.py file. Are you running your code in IDE or console ?

Comment: @pippo1980 it's in VSCode, and I'm using a virtual environment